# It is giving me error opening my Android Device Monitor but I found the folder and was able to open it

Tags: android, eclipse, monitor, ddms

So I open my Android Monitor Device to check the database that I have on my project and suddenly gave me this error:

[Here is the error of the Android Monitor Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05qeW.png)

So I look up if there is a way to deal with it and I ended up finding the folder of my monitor (see below).

[Here is the Monitor that I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGcbp.png)

It works perfectly but it is not showing anything. See Picture below...

[Android Device Monitor with nothing on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYHd.png)

Here is the configuration file of the monitor if it will help.

[Monitor Configuration Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGPAf.png)

I did not have this problem before and just happened today. There was an update that asked me last week, I don't know if that would affect my Android Studio running the Android Device Monitor. I have no idea how to fix it. I also saw that there was called Eclipse. What is the difference?